# How should I dispose of the vinyl shed walls?

Tags: vinyl, disposal

I have disassembled an old vinyl shed and removed all the metal, etc.  Now I need to know how and where to dispose of the vinyl walls?

Comment: Unfortunately, it can be difficult to recycle PVC. I've tried to do so with a batch of old siding. I hate to add that much uniform material to a landfill.

Answer (score 2):

If you have municipal trash collection, you'll want to contact the company in charge of pickup.  It's quite common for them to have a website, which typically has information about how to handle various types of waste.

If you're not sure who handles the collection. That information is usually available on the town/city website, or by calling the town/city.

If you take your waste to the dump (not sure if folks still have to do this), you could simply ask someone on your next trip.

Comment: My county has multiple trash drop-off centers (basically a fenced in lot with the large trash dumpsters for the various materials) that is open daily for large items and such. It's not the 'dump', as they take these away to empty every week or so. Contractor work and any extensive demolition work of your own requires renting a dumpster from them, but it just depends on how much you're looking to clear. Contact whoever gets your trash and ask about these as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just the trash, if you can cut it up. Or, you'll have to setup for a Bulk Trash Pickup with your Township, likely $10 for that stuff. But no recycling program will accept that & only Blinds To Go takes working vinyl blinds.